# Dynamically set the result of a TSQL query using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
SELECT  MyTable.Name,
        (
          SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(SUM(TotalDays), 0) <= 0 THEN 0 
                      ELSE SUM(TotalDays) 
          END AS Total
          FROM    Application AS Applications
          WHERE   (ID = MyTable.id)
        ) - MIN(Assignments) AS Excesses
FROM    MyTable
```

The above TSQL statement is a subquery in a main query. When i run it, if TotalDays is NULL or <=0, then Total is set to 0 (zero).

What i would like to do here is to set the result of the whole query(Excesses) to 0. I want **(Excesses)** which is the result of **Total - Min(Assignments)** to be set to 0 if its NULL or <=0.

I want the CASE WHEN to apply to the whole query but am struggling to get it right.

Comment: your question is not clear (for me at least)
can you please give the structure of the involved tables and what is the dat that you need to get with you quesy

Comment: I reformatted based on your brackets, is this right?

Comment: Yes the edited formating is very right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  MyTable.Name,
  CASE WHEN
    0 < (SELECT SUM(TotalDays) FROM Application WHERE ID = MyTable.id) - MIN(Assignments)
  THEN
    (SELECT SUM(TotalDays) FROM Application WHERE ID = MyTable.id) - MIN(Assignments)
  ELSE
    0
  END AS [Excesses]
FROM
  MyTable
```

Note: MS SQL Server won't exexute the two correlated-sub-queries independantly, it will infact recognise that they are the same and re-use the results.

Alternative:

```
SELECT
  MyTable.Name,
  CASE WHEN
    0 < SUM([application].TotalDays) - MIN([MyTable].Assignments)
  THEN
    SUM([application].TotalDays) - MIN([MyTable].Assignments)
  ELSE
    0 -- If either aggregate is NULL, 0 will still be returned
  END AS [Excesses]
FROM
  MyTable
LEFT JOIN
  Application
    ON [application].ID = [MyTable].id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  MyTable.Name, CASE WHEN ISNULL(SUM(TotalDays), 0) <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(TotalDays) END AS Total
FROM    Application AS Applications
JOIN    MyTable
ON      Applications.id = mytable.id
GROUP BY
        MyTable.id, MyTable.name
HAVING  CASE WHEN ISNULL(SUM(TotalDays), 0) <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(TotalDays) END > 0
```